# DENY INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE from Execution of Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, security, sql-update, roles, rights

```
CREATE LOGIN reader with password='Test@123#';
CREATE USER ureader for login reader;
grant connect to ureader;

GRANT SELECT TO ureader
DENY INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER, REFERENCES TO ureader
```

I have created new SQL Login using above script.
Basically i want one SQL USER which only allows select queries.
If procedure does have Insert / Update / Delete statements inside it, It should not allow it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[proc_testreport]
    @Mode int
AS           
BEGIN         
    IF(@Mode=1)      
    BEGIN       
        
        SELECT 1 AS 'DataValue','IP' AS 'DataText'
        UNION 
        SELECT 2 AS 'DataValue','OP' AS 'DataText'
        UNION
        SELECT 3 AS 'DataValue','MHC' AS 'DataText' 

        UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable] set test='F'

    END
END
```

When i do execute above procedure, it updates data on table [dbo].[TestTable], But it should not allow update it.

```
EXEC [Proc_TestReport] @Mode = 1
```

Can anyone help to restrict it.

Comment: When you execute the procedure were you logged in as the ureader?